# SQL select records based on not existing record

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with records like this:

```
ID | NAME | PHASE_ID | OPERATION_ID | EXT_ID |
---+------+----------+--------------+--------+
 1 | john |       5  |        5019  | aa-aaa |
 2 | ann  |       1  |        5048  | aa-aaa |
 3 | mary |       1  |        5048  | bb-bbb |
 4 | zack |       5  |        5019  | cc-ccc |
 5 | paul |       1  |        5048  | cc-ccc |
 6 | zoe  |       2  |        5555  | aa-aaa |
 7 | luke |       3  |        6666  | bb-bbb |
```

and I want to select all names from records having PHASE_ID=1 and OPERATION_ID=5048 for which there is no record with the same EXT_ID that have PHASE_ID=5 and OPERATION_ID=5019. In this table there is many combinations of PHASE_ID and OPERATION_ID for the same EXT_ID.

In this table name that fulfill this select would be only mary.

Any help composing that select would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `not exists`:

```
select distinct name
from t
where phase_id = 1 and operation_id = 5048 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ext_id = t.ext_id and
                        t2.phase_id = 5 and t2.operation_id = 5019
                 );
```